# Initiate Compare Files feature of SSMS2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server Management Studio 2012 has a toolbar called Compare Files.

I have tried to select files in Solution Explorer explorer as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/compare-files?view=sql-server-2014), but have been unable to get a file compare mode to work.

[image]

Comment: screenshot from ssms11 https://imgur.com/ZyjU9m7

Comment: Is your solution currently managed by a source control system?

Comment: I suspect you're after the toolbar located in `View`-> `Toolbars` -> `Compare Files`

Comment: @alroc, if that is the prerequisite that explains things. No, it isn't version controlled.

Comment: Read that documentation you linked to again. The feature allows you to compare versions within your source control system.

Comment: FWIW, I use Notepad++'s Compare feature to compare chunks of SQL code.

Comment: I was hoping for precisely the features of Notepad++, in SQL Server. I realised it was under that heading, but I was hoping it was doing a diff locally/not applicable to 2012. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Go to View -> Other Windows -> Command Window (Or Ctrl+Alt+A). In the Command Window type:

>Tools.DiffFiles <First file> <Second file>

Now in the new window you will see side-by-side differences and all buttons from "Compare Files" will work and will make sense.

Comment: Make sure the files have been saved to disk first.

Comment: Working example: 

`>Tools.DiffFiles "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\file_aaa.sql" "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\2\~vsA222.sql"`
No need for files to be saved. Use the context menu of the tab and click `Copy Full Path` and paste it within double quotes as shown in the example above `~vsA222.sql` is not saved by me.
An intellisense menu is available after writing the command `Tools.DiffFiles` but I found it confusing and does not give the full path of the file, leading to errors

Comment: BTW, the compare tab does not auto update if any of the files gets edited and saved

Comment: How to go about comparing 2 stored procs without saving to disk?